# WPF C# Change CheckBox Box Color when mousehovering?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I cannot change checkbox box color when the mouse is hovering on the checkbox. I'm new to WPF.

```xml
<CheckBox x:Name="TopMostCheckBox" 
            Content="TopMost" 
            FontFamily="Source Code Pro" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            IsChecked="True" 
            Background="#1F1F24" 
            BorderThickness="0" 
            BorderBrush="#1F1F24" 
            Foreground="#C95959" 
            Margin="493,325,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Here's what I mean:

[image: Photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember you should create a trigger with a setter:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    ...
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        <Setter
            Property="Background"
            TargetName="checkBoxBorder"
            Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
        ...
    </Trigger>
    ...
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: ill look into it tomorrow!